# Tsung MQTT Loadtest not working with SSL, finding possible way to disable ssl verification during load test

Tags: mqtt, tsung

I can't find option to disable SSL verification during load with tsung.
Note: I working when I loadtest with mqtt IP but now working when switch to SSL